# output of active view depends on the type of user

Tags: yii2

i have a leave application form hod can only  view the recommended application .other professors view all application for recommending. i have a single database table casual leave. it has a field recommendation i want if the recommendation field is recommended then hod view that apllication otherwise not, what can i do

```
this is my update code
  public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->start_date = strtotime($model->start_date);
        $model->start_date = date('Y-m-d',$model->start_date);
        $model->end_date = strtotime($model->end_date);
        $model->end_date = date('Y-m-d',$model->end_date);
        $model->date_of_request = strtotime($model->date_of_request);
        $model->date_of_request = date('Y-m-d',$model->date_of_request);
      //  $model->start_date = date_format($model->start_date,'Y-m-d');
     if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest && !Yii::$app->user->identity->username == 'hod' )
      {
        $model->recommendation = 'recommended';
      }else if(Yii::$app->user->identity->username == 'hod'){
        $model->status='sanctioned';
      }
       if($model->save()){
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
      }else{
          return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
         ]);



       }
 }
 else {
      return $this->render('create', [
           'model' => $model,
          //Yii::app()->user->setReturnUrl("casual-leaves/index");
   ]);


  //new line

}
}
```

view code

```
  public function actionView($id)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

where did i change , if the change is possible where i put condition

Answer (score 0):

If you use `RBAC` component you can set the types for any user and set conditions.

[RBAC Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html)

Then, you can do something like this:

```
if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
    //do something
}
else if(Yii::$app->authManager->checkAccess(Yii::$app->user->id, "hod")){
    //do something
}
else{
    //do something
}
```